# androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-constraintlayout

I have an Activity which xml layout contains Constraint layout and Linearlayout, RecyclerView as it's child layouts.

I have a button tied to an onCLick listener on the adapter, every time a click is performed. The application crashes and logs this error.

```
2019-09-11 09:52:19.713 22060-22060/com.myapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.myapp PID: 22060
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$LayoutParams cannot be cast to androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout$LayoutParams
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.getTargetWidget(ConstraintLayout.java:1144)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.setChildrenConstraints(ConstraintLayout.java:1028)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.updateHierarchy(ConstraintLayout.java:803)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1561)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1514)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:806)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:685)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6602)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:185)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:724)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:22071)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2422)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1504)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1761)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1392)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6752)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

This is my activity layout below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bill_border"
    tools:context=".ui.MyBillsActivity">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="60dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/number_of_parts"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/parts"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:padding="20dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/parts_button"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/number_of_parts">

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:text="2"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/send_bill_selector_background" />

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:text="3"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/send_bill_selector_background" />

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:text="4"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/send_bill_selector_background" />

                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
                            android:layout_width="35dp"
                            android:layout_height="35dp"
                            android:text="5"
                            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                            android:paddingTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingRight="1dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                            android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                            android:background="@drawable/send_bill_selector_background" />

                </LinearLayout>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/date_and_amount"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/number_of_parts"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/parts_button" />


                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/date_and_amount">

                        <!-- send bill recycler list -->
                        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                            android:id="@+id/recycler"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager"/>

                </LinearLayout>


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tap_text"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/error_outline"
                    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
                    android:text="This is a special text"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textSize="13sp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:paddingRight="4dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
                    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/payment_layout"/>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/send_button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    app:text="Submit Button"/>

        </FrameLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

This is my ADAPTER class below:

```
public class MysBillAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MysBillAdapter.MyBillViewHolder> {

    private String[] mDataset;

    public static class MyBillViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final AppCompatButton hideShow;
        private final LinearLayout percentageLayout;
        private final LinearLayout dueDateLayout;

        public View view;

        public MyBillViewHolder(View v) {
            super(v);
            hideShow = v.findViewById(R.id.hide_show);
            percentageLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.percentage_layout);
            dueDateLayout = v.findViewById(R.id.due_date_layout);
        }
    }

    // Provide a suitable constructor (depends on the kind of dataset)
    public MysBillAdapter(String[] myDataset) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
    }

    // Create new views (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public MysBillAdapter.MyBillViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout_bills, parent, false);
        return new MyBillViewHolder(v);
    }

    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyBillViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.hideShow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                holder.percentageLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); // This throws an exception
            }
        });

    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataset.length;
    }
}
```

My layout_bills xml

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/my_payment_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/bill_border"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="10dp">

    <!-- payment -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box1"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:background="@drawable/border"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <!-- percentage form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/percentage_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="3"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="3"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                android:background="@drawable/border_dark_blue" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="25dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="%"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="65dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:text="of 100"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp"
                />

        </LinearLayout>


        <!-- percentage form -->
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/due_date_layout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_dark_blue">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/my_calender"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="My payment Due Date"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:src="@drawable/arrow_right"
                android:gravity="left"
                android:paddingTop="4dp"
                android:paddingRight="1dp"
                android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                android:paddingLeft="1dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>



    <!-- edit -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/box3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/hide_show"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:background="@color/white"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:tag="hide"
            android:text="HIDE" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

My Activity class

```
public class MyBillActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter mAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_bill);



        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);


        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mAdapter = new MyBillAdapter(new String[]{"", "", "", ""});
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    }

}
```

Comment: post your `layout_bills` code

Comment: @Jaymin thank you, just added that.

Comment: please add your java file also where your adapter gets call

Comment: @truthsayer, I have debugged the code it is working fine. I did get any crash.

Comment: @BhavenShah I just added my Java file. please do re-check

Comment: If **MyBillViewHolder** variables are private, them how are you accessing them?

Comment: @Brainnovo It is a static inner class under the MysBillAdapter, Sincerely I can access them. Just to note, once I changed my code from Constraint Layout to LinearLayout completely. It works. Also if you check out the official example, a private variable was used: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview#java

Comment: Please provide the complete stack trace.

Comment: @MikeM. I just added the full stack trace

Comment: It seems like a `ConstraintLayout` is looking for a child `View` that has a constraint depending on it, and it's finding one of your `RecyclerView` items instead. It would've done the initial layout without a problem, because the `RecyclerView` wouldn't have been populated yet, but after you hide that nested layout, that inner `LinearLayout`, it triggers a re-layout. Are those layouts _exactly_ as you have them now? Was the root ID in `layout_bills` always `my_payment_layout`? Was the last constraint on the `tap_text` button always on `"@id/payment_layout"`?

Comment: The only think I can think of, atm, is that you possibly had those mixed up at some point, and there's still some old build remnants hanging around with the wrong IDs. Have you tried cleaning and rebuilding the project?